# Testing ASP.NET MVC2 service using Firefox Poster add-on

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to create a simple service using ASP.NET MVC2. I'm using Poster add-on [1](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2691/) for Firefox, but when I use POST by filling parameters using Poster, I can't reach them on the controller, here's the line I use:

```
string parameter = Request.Form["an_example_parameter"];
```

Am I doing something wrong? Any help on this? Thanks!

Comment: You don't use Request.Form in ASP.NET MVC. Go through the excellent tutorials on http://asp.net/mvc . :)

Comment: Yes, I know. All I want is to create a simple REST-like service using ASP.NET MVC, so I'm trying to access request parameters on the controller. But thanks for the tip anyway! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out.

> On a post the parameters are not added to the URL.  If you want them to be sent as the body of the post (e.g. 
>   like a form post), use the "Parameter Body" button to create the content.

http://code.google.com/p/poster-extension/issues/detail?id=43